# How to implement the Skynet 1m microbenchmark with core.async?

Tags: clojure, channel, coroutine, core.async

In order to try to understand core.async, I unsuccesfully tried to implement the "Skynet 1 million microbenchmark", which is:

> Creates an actor (goroutine, whatever), which spawns 10 new actors,
>   each of them spawns 10 more actors, etc. until one million actors are
>   created on the final level. Then, each of them returns back its
>   ordinal number (from 0 to 999999), which are summed on the previous
>   level and sent back upstream, until reaching the root actor. (The
>   answer should be 499999500000).

There are implementation in many languages here:

https://github.com/atemerev/skynet

Here's my totally broken attempt:

```
(defn skynet [chan num size div]
  (if (= 1 size)
    (>! chan num)
    (>! chan (reduce + (let [rc  (async/chan)
                             n   (/ size div)]
                          (doall (for [i [0 div]]
                                   (skynet rc (+ num (* i n)) n div))
                                 (for [i [0 div]] (<! rc))))))))
```

And I was trying to call it all from inside a go block at the REPL:

```
  (time (go (<!! (skynet (async/chan) 0 1000000 10))))
```

I'm probably seriously confused about many things concerning core.async (and lazy evaluation too).

How should I go about solving this problem and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [some limitations](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/wiki/Go-Block-Best-Practices) on what core.async is able to do, so you cannot use the `map` or `for` functions.

Your implementation is pretty close to the correct one. Some points:

1. `go` == one process, so you are just creating one process, not 1m
2. `<!!` is to be used outside go block
3. `<!` is to be used inside go blocks
4. You are using [for](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) incorrectly
5. `doall` accepts just one parameter

A working implementation that probably can be improved:

```
(defn skynet [parent num size div]
  (go ;; We create a new process each time skynet is called
    (if (= 1 size)
      (>! parent num)
      (let [self (chan)
            new-size (/ size div)]
        (dotimes [i div] ;; dotimes is more explicit for side effects 
          (skynet self (+ num (* i new-size)) new-size div))
    (loop [i div ;; Manual reduce 
           t   0]
      (if (zero? i)
        (>! parent t)
        (recur (dec i)
               (+ t (<! self)))))))))
```

And to call it:

```
 (time
   (do
     (def result (chan))
     (def x (skynet result 0 1000000 10))
     (<!! result)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! A lot of Clojure to study but this shall definitely help me a lot, not only your version but also your comments as to what is wrong in my code.  Weirdly some *"a/"* appeared in your last line of code, I edited it :)

Comment: Of course slower than just using a reducer, but that's the point of the benchmark. I tried to write a version of the `skynet` function that would return a channel containing the result (instead of taking one as argument), and use async/reduce instead of a manual reduce and could not find a way to do it. I would be interested in such a version. Anyway, Kudos !